# What exactly is BrowserEvent and NativeEvent for GWT?

Tags: events, gwt

What exactly is browser event? For example if I have a custom widget which contains a single button which overrides onBrowserEvent. And onBrowserEvent method is only called when you click on the button. I thought this event is called for all the events such as onMouseOver, onMouseOut, KeyPressed etc...

Also when you're adding DomHandler to make a widget listen to an event which is not supported by as a default. In the docs it says "Adds a native event handler to the widget and sinks the corresponding native event" What do you mean by native event in this context?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GWT has a concept of *sunk* events. All *sunk* events, but only those, are passed to a [`EventListener`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/EventListener.html)'s `onBrowserEvent`.

At the lowest level, you attach an `EventListener` to an `Element` using [`DOM.setEventListener`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#setEventListener%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Element,%20com.google.gwt.user.client.EventListener%29) and *sink* events with [`DOM.sinkEvents`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#sinkEvents%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Element,%20int%29) (or more recently [`DOM.setBitlessEvents`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#sinkBitlessEvent%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Element,%20java.lang.String%29)). To avoid memory leaks (particularly –if not only– in old IEs), you have to make sure you set an `Element`'s `EventListener` to `null` before the page unloads.

A `Widget` is an `EventListener` and handles a few of these things for you: it automatically calls `DOM.setEventListener` in its `onAttach` and `onDetach`, and it keeps track of *sunk* events: its `sinkEvents` is additive to make it easier to work with, and therefore has an `unsinkEvents` counterpart.

Later on, in GWT 1.6, event handlers have been added, and `addDomHandler` (and more recently `addBitlessDomHandler`) automatically calls  `sinkEvents` with the appropriate values (taken from the `DomEvent.Type` passed as argument); and to make all of this work, the default behavior of `onBrowserEvent` in widgets is to dispatch events to the registered handlers.

The reason for these *bitless* variants is that events were originally referred to as `int` constants in a bitfield, but browsers have more and more events so GWT started to run out of bits. The *bitless* variants are only usable for browsers that do *not* leak, as widgets don't keep track of which events have been registered that way to unregister them from their `onDetach`, contrary to bit-based events.

All these new `DomEvent`s (with their handlers) starting with GWT 1.6 are wrappers around a `NativeEvent`. There are two kinds of `GwtEvent`s: native ones (`DomEvent`s), which are dispatched by the browser, and *logical* ones which are dispatched by GWT itself and are not mapped to events at the DOM level. `addDomHandler` is only concerned about `DomEvent`s, aka *native events*.

Wrapping up: when you exit a text field that you just modified, the browser dispatches a `change` event. If the `TextBox` widget has *sunk* that event, its `onBrowserEvent` will be called with an `Event` (which is just a legacy subclass of `NativeEvent`) representing that event. The default implementation of `onBrowserEvent` then creates a `ChangeEvent` and dispatches it to the registered `ChangeHandler`s.

Comment: What exactly is sunk events? When you say "widget has sunk that event" what does that exactly means?

Comment: English verb: sink/sank/sunk. In the context of GWT, an event is _sunk_ if `sinkEvents` has been called with its code as argument.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer now I got clearification of BrowserEvents...Nice  Thanks.